# essential tools for .net programmer?

Tags: .net

This question looks familiar with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187/essential-programming-tools, but I want to focus on .NET programming. Beyond Windows and Visual Studio, which tools are your daily-need to get your job done? Free, open-source code tools are preferred :)

I've been using these tools:

- Resharper - top of its class, but not free
- NUnit - trying to get used with it.
- VisualSVN + TortoiseSVN

which other tools I should know and use?

Comment: Perhaps this should be marked Community Wiki?

Answer (score 6):

http://www.hanselman.com/tools

Scroll down to section: ***A (.NET) Developer's Life***

Answer (score 2):

My recommendations

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

[Anjlab SQL Server Profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) or even Microsoft SQL Server Profiler

[PowerCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99)

[Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

[Studio Styles](http://studiostyles.info/)

Answer (score 0):

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm): Regular expression tool with .NET syntax.

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/): +1 from Hanselmans's post above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into serious debugging or programming where you need to convert between Hex and Decimal go for a good converter, this will save lot of time, especially when debugging with error codes in hex etc. See http://onequestionatime.blogspot.in/2012/05/1-what-is-easiest-way-to-convert.html for a fast and easy converter